# How can i use ng-class variable from controller?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have set ng-class on the div i want to apply css when file is selected so below onSelect i want to change div color to green. How can i achieve this task using AngularJs ?

html

```
<div class="text-arrow" ng-class="{activeBackground:applyActive}">File Selection<span class="arrow-div"></span></div>
```

css

```
.activeBackground{
       background-color: green;
    }
```

script.js

```
$scope.onSelect = function (e) {
        $scope.applyActive = true;
}
```

Comment: current code should work..is there any console error?

Comment: there is a typo her `ng-class="{activeBackground:applyActive}"`  it should be `ng-class="{'activeBackground':applyActive}"`

Comment: @AlainIb no..`'` single qoute will be used only when class name will have special character..it will work without `'` too

Comment: I want to make variable true onSelect but with above answer it looks like it will be true all the scenarios also if i want to add more classes lets say completeBackground and set different color to it how can i do that

Comment: If i dont need single quote then whats the problem with my code

Comment: how do you call the function `onSelect` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [working plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aaL0KhxFAAKweFr5AFpW?p=preview) of what you're trying to achieve.

```
 <div ng-class="{ activeBackground: applyActive }">File Selection</div>
 <button ng-click="toggleBackground()">Toggle background</button>
```

Possible issues with your code:

- you have another style that overwrites the background
- the `onSelect` function you mentioned is not invoked properly